# ERROR: could not load library libperl.so, PostgreSQL trying to CREATE EXTENSION plperlu

Tags: linux, postgresql, perl, suse

I want to use the perl language in a postgres function.

I am attempting to:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plperlu
```

...via pgAdmin 4 connected to postgres 10 and I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/var/lib/pgsql10/lib/postgresql/plperl.so": libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
SQL state: XX000
```

I look for the library:

```
find -name libperl.so
```

...and I see it in these locations:

```
./usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/i586-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
./usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
```

So I conclude that it is already on my server distribution, but isn't in the location postgres is looking so I search and find this link:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D960CB61B694CF459DCFB4B0128514C207B2C9DC%40exadv11.host.magwien.gv.at

...and I am opting do this (from the link above, but I have different paths):
 "- Add the directory that contains libperl.so to /etc/ld.so.conf and
  run "ldconfig" as root user.  Then start the PostgreSQL server."

So I find the config file:

```
find -name ld.so.conf
```

And get this path:

```
./etc/ld.so.conf
```

...and edit the file:

```
vi ./etc/ld.so.conf
```

... and add this path:

```
./usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/
```

... load the new config:

```
ldconfig
```

... restart pg:

```
systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
```

... run this query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plperlu;
```

...and get the same error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/var/lib/pgsql10/lib/postgresql/plperl.so": libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    SQL state: XX000
```

...when I replace the previous path and add this path:

```
/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE
```

..to `ld.so.conf`, I get:

```
 ERROR:  could not load library "/var/lib/pgsql10/lib/postgresql/plperl.so": /var/lib/pgsql10/lib/postgresql/plperl.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_handshake
SQL state: XX000
```

... a little different error, but I don't know if I am closer or further away.

How do I get PostgreSQL pointed to the correct library so I can use perl?

I have:

- PostgreSQL 10.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18), 64-bit
- pgAdmin 4 2.0
- SUSE Linux Enterprise 12 64-bit virtual server

UPDATE 1:

I received help from the postgres general email list: The existing perl was likely built using an older OS (which I guess I have) therefore doesn't work (handshake) with a current version of postgres (v10). I hope to update my OS which will update my server OS distribution version of perl, which should be a postgres v10 supported version of perl. I'll try to come back with confirmation/an answer after we upgrade our OS. Any additional color or possible causes welcome though.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this problem ?